# Sails.js, Ember, Handlebars and configuration via grunt-ember-templates: templates file not created

Tags: sails.js, handlebars.js, grunt-ember-templates

Found the link [Sails JS with EJS but linker to compile handlebars public templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21951961/sails-js-with-ejs-but-linker-to-compile-handlebars-public-templates)
and it looks straight forward but somehow it does not work with my current sails version with jade

Here's the current Grunt Configuration in tasks/config/emberTemplates.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.config.set('emberTemplates', {
  dev: {
    compile: {
      options: {
        amd: true,
        templateBasePath: /assets\/templates\//
      },
      files: {
      ".tmp/public/templates.js": ['assets/templates/**/*.hbs']
    }
  }
 }
});
  //console.log('loading grunt-ember-template');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ember-templates');
};
```

I can see that the task gets picked up by Grunt on

```
 > sails lift --prod

 ..... 
 Grunt :: Running "emberTemplates:dev" (emberTemplates) task
```

But the file ./tmp/public/templates.js never gets created.

I banged my head against the wall for 8 hours and don't know where to go.
Any help is apreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the dev: section.. as soon as I removed the dev: section it worked:

module.exports = function (grunt) {

```
grunt.config.set('emberTemplates', {
  compile: {
     options: {
     amd: false,
     templateBasePath: /assets\/templates\//
     },
  files: {
  ".tmp/public/templates.js": ['assets/templates/**/*.hbs']
    }
 });

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ember-templates');
};
```